# Route incoming network to different vNIC in windows

Tags: windows, networking, routing

Is there a way in Windows to distinguish incoming traffic (from different shared network devices under the same network) and route them to different vNIC?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure, but I, havent seen this ever in the wild there is an IF flag in the route command, but I think it's for outgoing traffic. To separate the networks I use VLAN's. I windows the drivers from Microsoft may not support them, but for instance Intel pro set drivers do.